# Google Analytics API v4: Multiple date ranges returns only one range in dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am creating a Google Analytics v4 API call, with two date ranges, two dimensions, and two metrics.

The dimensions are ga:source and ga:date, and the metrics are ga:users and ga:newUsers.  When I receive a response, the rows contain data for two date ranges, but the dimensions only include the ga:date value for the first date range.  First, below is the data I will pass into the API.

```
request in pastebin
```

https://pastebin.com/G5PDWSZ1

Second, is the response I get in return:

```
response in pastebin
```

https://pastebin.com/BwD6bztA

Notice in the return that each row contains two dimensions, but two dates with two metrics each.  If each dateRow will represent a different set of dates, shouldn't each dateRow contain it's own set of dimensions for that range of dates?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the PHP documentation for [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet):

> The request can have a maximum of 2 date ranges. The response will contain a set of metric values for each combination of the dimensions for each date range in the request. So, if there are two date ranges, there will be two set of metric values, one for the original date range and one for the second date range.

So what this means is for each date range you will receive a unique set of metrics, not dimensions. Dimensions can be thought of as categorizing terms, that can group or separate the metric values. Metrics describe the actual data found for time span. This being said, it would make sense that multiple date ranges would return a value for each metric supplied, but not necessarily for each dimension. It is very possible that one date range contained no metric values under a dimension category, as such that dimension will not be shown, since dimensions need a metric value to describe.

Comment: The issue is that ga:date is added for the sole purpose of receiving day by day data, otherwise we would receive data for the whole span, not day by day.  So we should have day by day data for both spans, thus each day would have a dimension clarifying the day.  This happens for the first span, but since there is only one set of dimensions, it is never specified the day for the 2nd metric set.

Comment: row {
    dimension {
        day 1 (range 1)
   }
   dateRange1 {
       metric value
   }
   dateRange2 {
       metric value
}
}

Comment: Where is day 1 (range 2)?

Comment: Can you please point to a specific line number of your output where this is occurring? I just looked through each response row and everyone of them has both dimensions defined.

Comment: Starting at line 31, this contains a row.  It has two dimension values (ga:source, ga:date), and two dates ranges (line 56, 81), and four metrics values (line 61, 86).  The day value, from the dimension, specified on line 37, corresponds to date range 1, line 56.  The current day for date range two, line 81, is never specified (it should be 20170807).

Comment: You are not reading the results correctly. That is saying the dimensions (direct) and 20170730, on date range one you have metric values of 1 and 1, for date range two you have metric values of 0 and 0, as in the data is 0 not nothing. Observe the report row at 1690 and the next one at 1769. Here you have non-zero data for your second date range, but still one dimension value for ga:date

Comment: On line 1696, this is a date range 1 date (20170805).  If Date range two has values here, where is the dimension telling me which day that falls on?  Date range 2 starts on 20170807.

Comment: You must have inputted your data wrong then. All dimension entries with 20170805 I can see have data for your second date range only.